# What's the easiest way to get Vim with Python 3 support?

Tags: vim, python3

I have Ubuntu 14.04 installed and Vim in its repos is compiled without Python 3 support. Because of that, python-mode plugin can't work with Python 3 code. What's the easiest way to get Vim with Python 3 support?

Answer (score 17):

It seems on Debian-based systems (at least) you can't have your cake and eat it too. It's either Python 2 or Python 3. [Due to how the Python libraries are built](https://www.mail-archive.com/vim_dev@googlegroups.com/msg22562.html), you can only use one variant within a Vim session. You *can* build with both, but if Python 2 is called in Vim, then Python 3 cannot be called in the same session, and vice versa. On Arch Linux as well, Vim is only compiled with one of Python 2 (`vim`, `gvim`) or Python 3 (`vim-python3`, `gvim-python3`).

---

## Before 16.04

To rebuild the Vim that the repositories provide:

```
sudo apt-get build-dep vim
apt-get source vim
cd vim-*  # it will be vim-7.4.something
```

Edit `debian/rules` and replace:

```
ALLINTERPFLAGS+=--enable-pythoninterp --with-python-config-dir=$(shell python-config --configdir)
ALLINTERPFLAGS+=--disable-python3interp
```

With:

```
ALLINTERPFLAGS+=--enable-pythoninterp=dynamic --with-python-config-dir=$(shell python-config --configdir)
ALLINTERPFLAGS+=--enable-python3interp=dynamic --with-python3-config-dir=$(shell python3-config --configdir)
```

Then run:

```
dpkg-buildpackage -us -uc
```

Have lunch. (Or tea if you used `-j $(nproc)`.)

Now, multiple `.deb` files will have been created in the parent directory. To see which:

```
cd ..
ls vim*.deb
```

Along with the particular variant you want to install (`vim`, `vim-gnome`, `vim-gtk`, etc.), you'll have to install `vim-common_*.deb`, `vim-runtime_*.deb`, and for the GUI versions, `vim-gui-common_*.deb`. For example, with `vim-gnome`, and the current version of `vim` in the repositories:

```
sudo dpkg -i vim-gnome_7.4.052-1ubuntu3_amd64.deb vim-common_7.4.052-1ubuntu3_amd64.deb vim-gui-common_7.4.052-1ubuntu3_all.deb vim-runtime_7.4.052-1ubuntu3_all.deb
```

Then:

```
$ vim --version | grep python
+cryptv          +linebreak       +python/dyn      +viminfo
+cscope          +lispindent      +python3/dyn     +vreplace
```

---

The [pi-rho/dev PPA](https://launchpad.net/~pi-rho/+archive/ubuntu/dev) builds Vim in this fashion, so you can use the PPA instead of manually building it.

---

## 16.04

As of 16.04, Ubuntu builds Vim with Python 3 support. Python 2 support is provided by [the `-py2` packages](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=xenial&section=all&arch=any&keywords=vim%20py2&searchon=names) (`vim-nox-py2`, `vim-gnome-py2`, etc.).

---

Related:

- [How do I get Vim to be able to run both python and python3 on a Linux system in the same session?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/779/205) on Vi and Vim.

Comment: Vim compiled this way gives me an error when trying to load pymode functions: This Vim cannot execute :py3 after using :python. When I was using Gentoo instead of Ubuntu, vim used python 3 and this problem did not exist.

Comment: @CrabMan Read the first paragraph.

Comment: @CrabMan What you can try is to build only with Python3 (essentially swapping python3 and python in the lines that already existed). Then anything that tried to load python2 will fail.

Comment: YouCompleteMe unavailable: requires Vim compiled with Python 2.x support. I think it's one of the most important vim extensions I use so that's not an option.

Comment: Also as far as I understand I can just include "py3 3" line in my .vimrc and it will have the same effect as compiling vim with just python3 support.

Comment: @CrabMan Well, once `py3` is loaded, `py` becomes unavailable, so do it early enough in `.vimrc` and it's the same effect.