# How to build .deb files of vim which support both python2 and python3 on Ubuntu14.04?

Tags: compiling, packaging, deb, vim

I tried [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/585237/whats-the-easiest-way-to-get-vim-with-python-3-support) tutorial but when I ran the command `dpkg-buildpackage -us -uc`, it failed....

I don't know what's wrong.

This is the log:

```
Test results:
test87 FAILED
TEST FAILURE
Makefile:49: recipe for target 'report' failed
make[2]: *** [report] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/jmjoy/tmp/src/vim-7.4.273/src/vim-nox/testdir'
Makefile:1866: recipe for target 'test' failed
make[1]: *** [test] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/jmjoy/tmp/src/vim-7.4.273/src/vim-nox'
debian/rules:304: recipe for target 'install-stamp-vim-basic' failed
make: *** [install-stamp-vim-basic] Error 1
dpkg-buildpackage: 错误: fakeroot debian/rules binary 提供错误退出状态 2
```

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu? Did you try disabling the tests? Ubuntu 14.04 has 7.4.052, not 7.4.273.

Comment: how is this vim related? oh, building a vim package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this command instead of `dpkg-buildpackage -us -uc` and all is fine:

```
DEB_BUILD_OPTIONS=nocheck dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot -us -uc -b
```

Tests are disabled and there are only built binary packages.

Comment: I hoped this worked for the original poster.

Comment: @GrantBowman what do you mean? This works for me. Why should it not work for others?

Comment: @A.B. Well, I didn't have to disable tests for it build fine on 14.10. I'm guessing OP has some other problem here.

Comment: @muru I probably assumed he wants to build up quickly a binary.

Comment: @muru I had the same problem in 15.04.

Comment: Sorry, I am too late to confirm this answer, it works well! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I found that for the vim source and official vim deb source package even outside debuild, running `make test` the failed tests would sometimes be cached in `/src/testdir/failed/` and fail even if they succeeded on a clean tarball extract, they will still fail cuz the directory isn't empty on second try.

These leftovers would not be cleaned with `make clean` from the root directory, it can be removed with `make -C src/testdir clean` as far as I remember (but please double check, cuz I am almost 100% certain this particular folder was a leftover `/failed`).

So if your package failed building just once, this issue could arise if that directory is non-empty. When it will fail it will fail on `popupvim.vim` ~4-6 failed tests

Do a `diff -aq` on a clean upstream tar extract with your building directory after running `make clean`

Otherwise try outside debuild and see if tests fail.

If and when you try to create a package, take note:

The tests will fail if they are run as `make test` this is where you get a LOT of failed tests, like ~33-60 and it will screw up your terminal when it comes to `test_gui.vim` or `test_alot.vim`. (This is also mentioned when building,

*"If you have trouble making tests, `cd src && make test`"* see [Makefile](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/b96a32ef1a95dd4ebf9413d686bccb1b4645f74b/Makefile#L30)

So instead for building tests use:

`make -C src/ test`