# vim with python3 compatibility

Tags: 14.04, vim, python3

So I followed this way [What's the easiest way to get Vim with Python 3 support?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/585237/whats-the-easiest-way-to-get-vim-with-python-3-support)
which didn't work 
 and this one http://www.xorpd.net/blog/vim_python3_install.html
that did work.
the thing is each time I reboot my ubuntu, /opt/vim74/* is removed and I have to install it again.

so my question is why is it removed at each reboot and how to I make it stay?